# Cannot read property 'BarRenderer' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqplot

i'm trying out jqplot just to use for bar graphs but no matter what example I try, i keep getting this error in the console:

"Cannot read property 'BarRenderer' of undefined"

i did a google search and can't find much of anything on this and i don't understand.. any help would be great.  i'm using asp.net MVC 4

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "View1";
}

<h2>View1</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/jqPlot/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<div id="chart1" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var s1 = [200, 600, 700, 1000];
        var s2 = [460, -210, 690, 820];
        var s3 = [-260, -440, 320, 200];
        // Can specify a custom tick Array.
        // Ticks should match up one for each y value (category) in the series.
        var ticks = ['May', 'June', 'July', 'August'];

        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1, s2, s3], {
            // The "seriesDefaults" option is an options object that will
            // be applied to all series in the chart.
            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                rendererOptions: { fillToZero: true }
            },
            // Custom labels for the series are specified with the "label"
            // option on the series option.  Here a series option object
            // is specified for each series.
            series: [
                { label: 'Hotel' },
                { label: 'Event Regristration' },
                { label: 'Airfare' }
            ],
            // Show the legend and put it outside the grid, but inside the
            // plot container, shrinking the grid to accomodate the legend.
            // A value of "outside" would not shrink the grid and allow
            // the legend to overflow the container.
            legend: {
                show: true,
                placement: 'outsideGrid'
            },
            axes: {
                // Use a category axis on the x axis and use our custom ticks.
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: ticks
                },
                // Pad the y axis just a little so bars can get close to, but
                // not touch, the grid boundaries.  1.2 is the default padding.
                yaxis: {
                    pad: 1.05,
                    tickOptions: { formatString: '$%d' }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've recreated the above snippet and it works fine. Are you sure all the files that you are including at the top of your script have been uploaded to your server? The only way I can replicate your error is by not uploading "jquery.jqplot.min.js" to my server.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'BarRenderer' of
>   undefined(anonymous function) @ jqplot.barRenderer.min.js:57(anonymous
>   function) @ jqplot.barRenderer.min.js:57

Comment: i picked all the files manually (i actually browsed to the file directly to make sure i dont assume or misspell) so i'm sure the file is there.. i ended up using Google's Chart API instead which worked.  thank you though for the response

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue It is mainly related to js loading issue . Put those reference files in master layout page

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing the Scripts.Render at the bottom of View_Layout.cshtml
as it was calling jquery twice.

```
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")        <-- remove this line
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")     <-- remove this line
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) <-- remove this line

    </body>
  </html>
```